# How to refer to a bean created in context.xml?

Tags: java, spring, maven

In my project, there is a main maven module that keeps every thing inside 1 `context.xml`

I have a separate maven module where we are trying to use annotations (`@Component`, `@Autowired`) instead of stuffing everything in 1 `context.xml`.

In a class that I create

```
@Component
public class ActiveDirectoryConfigurationStore implements ConfigurationStore<ActiveDirectoryConfiguration> {
 ....
}
```

This bean in `java` looks like

```
public class CacheFactory implements FactoryBean<Cache>, DisposableBean {
...
}
```

I would like to refer to a bean that is created inside this big `context.xml`

```
<bean id="usersCacheFactory" class="cache.impl.CacheFactory">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="users"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="db"/>
    </bean>
```

How can I refer to this bean `usersCacheFactory` using `@Autowired` annotation in my `ActiveDirectoryConfigurationStore` class?
Note that `ActiveDirectoryConfigurationStore` is in different module than this bean

Comment: To autowire by name, specify `@Autowired @Qualifier("usersCacheFactory")`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using @ImportResource ? E.g. as below

```
@Component
@ImportResource(value = { "classpath:/com/yourcompany/othermodule/context.xml" })
public class ActiveDirectoryConfigurationStore implements ConfigurationStore<ActiveDirectoryConfiguration> {

 @Autowired
 @Qualifier(value="usersCacheFactory")
 CacheFactory usersCacheFactory;

 ....
}
```